# Front/Back Inserter In_place

Tags: c++, iterator, c++14

During my learning, I came across front and back iterators an I wanted to know if there was a way to get them to create container elements in place. From the documentation, it seems that containers need to implement push_back functions to be used with back_iterator for example. But is there a way to emplace on element creation?

Comment: There's `emplace_back` method, but there's no corresponding `back_emplacer`. It's not clear what the latter could look like or how it could be used, seeing as `emplace_back` takes an aebitrary number of arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking about is conceptually impossible.

An iterator as a concept represents an abstraction of some object which references an element of some type within a series of elements of that type. As such, the [basic `Iterator` concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Iterator) has as a core feature the ability to dereference the iterator. That is `*it` is a legal expression (though the basic Iterator doesn't say what the return value of this is).

[`back_insert_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator) implements `*it` by... not implementing it. The [OutputIterator concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/OutputIterator) allows `*it`, but the result of it is unspecified, so you can't really use it directly. Instead, you're supposed to use it in an expression like `*it++ = value;`. It is the `operator=` overload that actually calls `push_back`.

This mimics the behavior of natural iterators like pointers. It allows an OutputIterator to *pretend* to allow you to assign to an existing value, while you're actually using `operator=` to call `container.push_back`. The `*` and `++` are just there to match the interface of ForwardIterators.

But `operator=` is an operator. It's a function which takes exactly and only two arguments: the iterator (the left-hand side) and the value to assign to it.

`emplace`-like functions work by calling a constructor with an arbitrary sequence of parameters. There's no way to do that through `operator=`. And since the interface of OutputIterator is limited to just that, there is no effective way for an iterator to use in-place construction like this.

---

Note that there is technically a way to do it. What you need is a way to pack multiple values in a single value:

```
auto it = back_emplacer(...);
*it++ = std::forward_as_tuple(...);
```

The `operator=` would look like this:

```
template<typename ...Args>
back_emplace_iterator &operator=(std::tuple<Args...> &&args)
{
  std::apply(
    [container](auto ...&&args)
      {container->emplace_back(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);},
    std::forward<std::tuple<Args>>(args));
  return *this;
}
```

Of course, the downside is that you have to manually pack your data in a forwarding `tuple`.

Comment: Note that there are two overloads of `operator=`, one for `const typename Container::value_type&` (i.e. copy) and one for `typename Container::value_type&&` (i.e. move).